# Использую прокси сервер перенаправляет на неизвестную страницу

Tags: golang

Код работал нормально до тех пор пока я не добавил поддержку прокси-соединение. Теперь ведет себя как-то странно, или это я странный :/

```
beautifulReader, err := ioutil.ReadFile("proxy.txt")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}


str := string(beautifulReader) 
randoms := strings.Split(str, "\r\n")
bestProxyServer := randInt(len(randoms))

proxyUrl, err := url.Parse(randoms[bestProxyServer])
httpClient := &http.Client { Transport: &http.Transport { Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl) } }



spvKeyOutput := fmt.Sprintf("%X", byteStrong) 
request_url := "http://formm.ru/handler.php"
// 要 POST的 参数
form := url.Values {
    "username": {spvKeyOutput},
}

body := bytes.NewBufferString(form.Encode())
rsp, err := httpClient.Post(request_url, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", body)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer rsp.Body.Close()
body_byte, err := ioutil.ReadAll(rsp.Body)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(body_byte))
```

Без прокси-сервера код работает нормально, подключаю прокси выдает `404` с неизвестной мне страницей - "*Форма обратной связи-конструктор форм,генератор форм,создать форму,мастер форм*". Понятия не имею почему так происходит.

Все теперь понятно. При помощи прокси подается запрос на сайт *http://formm.ru/handler.php* то есть на все видимый домен, глобальный домен, а я думал что запрос подается на мой локальный сервер (сайт) `formm.ru`. Как отправить запрос через прокси именно на локальный адрес?

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите чтобы ваш запрос прошёл до прокси сервера где-то интернете и этот прокси перенаравил на ваш локальный сервер?

Comment: @biosckon чтоб прошел запрос до локального сервера через прокси. Вообще я буду менять уже на полноценное доменное имя, но сейчас для практики использую локальный сервер (Денвер) и нужно что-то такое попробовать реализовать.

Comment: прокси сервер должен понимать куда ему посылать запрос так что вам нужно поменять `request_url := "http://formm.ru/handler.php"` на ваш "локальный" сервер домем или IP адрес которого должен быть виден прокси серверу.

Comment: @biosckon пробовал следовать документации денвера, заменять на ip адрес машины в локальной сети, но не помогло, и я не очень понимаю какая ссылка нужна на локальный сервер, можете поподробнее пожалуйста обьяснить.

Comment: Клиент, серевер и прокси работают на одной и тойже машине?

Comment: @biosckon да, прокси я взял рандомный, первый попавшейся.

Comment: не совсем понял как рандомный что у вас в `proxy.txt`?

Comment: @biosckon лежит единственный https://109.254.185.60:3128 взял первый попавшейся прокси сервер с сайта.

Comment: Это внешний сервер который нахдится на Украине похоже. Ваш локальный [частный адрес](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81#%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_IP-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0_IPv4) не виден в интернете. Чтобы прокси видел ваш адрес ваша машина должена быть видна в интернете. Для этого надо будет настраивать NAT. А это отдельный вопрос. В интернете виден только динамический IP адрес вашего модема (если у вас простой домашний DSL).

Comment: @biosckon понятно. Спасибо за ответ.